# Cast string to object name

Tags: python, pyqt

I try do something like this.

```
list = []

for i in range(100):
    list.append("self.label_"+ i)
for i in list:
      convetToObject(i)    
      i.setText("Hello")
```

Ideas ?

Comment: Does `self` already contains the 100 labels or does the **convertToObject** thing has to create them as well?

Comment: Use a dictionary to link a name to an object {"self.label_x":object}  dict["self.label_x"].setText("Hello")

Comment: The real question is, _why_ are you doing something like this? I can pretty much guarantee that this is the wrong way of doing whatever it is you're actually trying to accomplish. This is an example of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Also, don't name your object `list`, or you won't be able to use the built-in function `list()`.

Comment: because i have a window with 100 labels. and i want modify everything at time

Comment: Just as I thought: there is a different and much better solution for that. I've outlined it in my answer.

Comment: ...Do you actually have a hundred lines in your source code with `self.label_0 = Label()`, `self.label_1 = Label()`, etc.?

Comment: Yup, Tiger's answer will help you go further, with `setattr` as I proposed you’ll have hard time retrieving the objects afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Creating a bunch of numbered string variables and trying to turn them into references for objects is an anti-pattern that is very, very rarely needed (see the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Here's a better approach:

```
self.labels = []

for i in range(100):
    l = Label()
    l.setText('Hello')
    self.labels.append(l)
```

N.B.: I don't have experience with PyQT, so the implementation details may be different. However, this is almost certainly the design pattern you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working in an instance `self` with a bunch of attributes that start with `'label_'`, you should be able to do something like this instead:

```
labels = [getattr(self, k) for k in dir(self) if k.startswith('label_')]
for l in labels:
    l.setText('Hello')
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 you can use the built-in function `exec()` to execute a string containing python-code, in python 2.7 i think the exec statement can do the same.
Here an exampe in python 3, pyqt5:

```
for i in range(25):
    n = i + 1
    on = 'label_{}'.format(n)               # the name of the object
    src = 'self.{} = QtWidgets.Qlabel()'.format(on) # string to create the object

    exec(src)                           # execute the code
```

either set Text in this loop

```
    src = 'self.{}.setText("{}")'.format(on,n)
    exec(src)
```

or set an objectname to access the object later:

```
    src = 'self.{0}.setObjectName("{0}")'.format(on)
    exec(src)
```

I added the objects to a QVBoxLayout, else you have to set a parent in the string creating the object

```
    src = 'self.layout.addWidget(self.{})'.format(on)
    exec(src)
```

example for later setting of text:

```
for i in range(25):
    n = i + 1
    on = 'label_{}'.format(n)          
    label = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLabel,on)
    label.setText(str(n))
```